# How to select specific columns of tables while exporting with the SQL Server export wizard?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I want to export some tables from a remote server. But there is a problem I can only get specific columns of the tables I don't have permission to other columns.

I set them in edit Mapping by editing SQL but it still tries to get the other columns of tables which are not selected and not in sql

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On `Specify Table Copy or Query` tab choose `Write a query`...
And write your statement with appropriate columns.

[image]

Comment: what do I have to do there ? Create statemens exc.

Comment: Just select from your table with columns where you have permission: `Select AYRILISK , AYRILISADI , AKTIFEH  FROM AYRILIS`